# An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details ( linq)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Since I am new to entity framework and linq, I don't know much about entity framework or linq. Currently I am facing exception `An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.` on:

```
foreach (var items in query)
            {
                var outtime= from x in con.CHECKINOUTs
                             select x;
            }
```

But it works perfectly if I do query outside foreach loop.

```
var outtime= from x in con.CHECKINOUTs
                   select x;
```

What I need to do is for each items of query, i need to add another field based on outtime.

Please suggest me what to do? and how to get more detail information about exception `An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.`

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the inner exception as suggested?

Do you get the error if you try like this?

```
foreach (var items in query)
{
       var outtime= (from x in con.CHECKINOUTs
                      select x).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes I get same error whether using .tolist() or not. And I also check inner exception but can't find useful information.

Comment: This problem is solved after Enabling Multiple Active Result Sets in connection string( MultipleActiveResultSets=true ).